# How to set the from name in php mailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I can actually send the emails but I want to change the email `from name`. When I send emails, it comes into the receiver mailbox with my mail id. I want to change that to some other names. Kindly help me to do that. This is my code

```
    <?php
    $mailto = $_POST['mail_to'];
    $mailSub = $_POST['mail_sub'];
    $mailMsg = $_POST['mail_msg'];
   require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail ->IsSmtp();
   $mail ->SMTPDebug = 0;
   $mail ->SMTPAuth = true;
   $mail ->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
   $mail ->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
   $mail ->Port = 465; // or 587
   $mail ->IsHTML(true);
   $mail ->Username = "dkdev006@gmail.com";
   $mail ->Password = "password";
   $mail ->SetFrom("Kreatz.in");
   $mail ->Subject = $mailSub;
   $mail ->Body = $mailMsg;
   $mail ->AddAddress($mailto);
   if(!$mail->Send())
   {
       echo "Mail Not Sent";
   }
   else
   {
       echo "Mail Sent";
   }
```

Comment: The code { setFrom } is not working

Answer (score 0):

Look at [the docs on this method](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_setFrom).

You have `$mail ->SetFrom("Kreatz.in");`, which is neither a "nice" name nor an email address, so I don't know what you're trying to do there. You probably want to do this:

```
$mail ->setFrom('dkdev006@gmail.com', 'Kreatz.in');
```

Bear in mind that you're using gmail to send through, so you are not allowed to set arbitrary from addresses, though you can create fixed aliases in gmail prefs.

You're also using an old version of PHPMailer, and have based your code on an obsolete example, so [get the latest version](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).